# Plotting frequency of 1000 items space issue

Tags: python-3.x, graph, plot, nlp, nltk

[image]

I am trying to plot the frequency of 1000 words using nltk's FreqDist plot, and all the words are smashed together in the plot shown. Is there a way to plot the words on the Y-axis and kind of have a scrolling image? Also I am using Python 3.

Comment: What's the use of a graph if you have to scroll to see all of it? The point of a graph is to grasp its shape – you need to see all of it at once to do that, I'd say.

Comment: Anyway, you probably have to create the plot with `matplotlib` yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Try `plot.ly`.

First create an account on https://plot.ly

Then, see https://plot.ly/python/getting-started/:

```
$ pip install plotly
$ python -c "import plotly; plotly.tools.set_credentials_file(username='DemoAccount', api_key='lr1c37zw81')"
```

After installing and initializing the API. Take a look at the reference: https://plot.ly/python/reference/

To plot a *word-frequency* graph, see https://plot.ly/python/time-series/

And with the following code:

```
>>> import plotly.plotly as py
>>> from plotly.graph_objs import *
>>> from nltk.corpus import brown
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> word_freq = Counter(brown.words())
>>> words, freqs = zip(*word_freq.most_common()[:1000])
>>> data = Data([ Scatter(x=words, y=freqs)])
>>> plot_url = py.plot(data, filename='brown_freqs'
```

It will produce https://plot.ly/~alvations/102:

[image]

Note that there is a maximum no. of data points that you can squeeze in and you might see this warning/error message:

> Woah there! Look at all those points! Due to browser limitations,
>   Plotly has a hard time graphing more than 500k data points for line
>   charts, or 40k points for other types of charts. Here are some
>   suggestions: (1) Trying using the image API to return an image instead
>   of a graph URL (2) Use matplotlib (3) See if you can create your
>   visualization with fewer data points
>
> If the visualization you're using aggregates points (e.g., box plot,
>   histogram, etc.) you can disregard this warning.